# Prove a 4-cycle exists in a graph with 100 vertices, each with degree of atleast 50

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I hope I wrote the question well since it is my attempt at translating from the book. If it isnt clear enough, The question states that in every graph as described in the title a simple cycle of length 4 exists.

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may assume that the graph is not complete. Choose two nonadjacent vertices $u$ and $v$. Now $N(u)$ and $N(v)$ are $50$-element subsets of the $98$-element set $V(G)\setminus\{u,v\}$, so
$$|N(u)\cap N(v)|=|N(u)|+|N(v)|-|N(u)\cup N(v)|\ge50+50-98=2.$$
So $u$ and $v$ and their two common neighbors form a subgraph $K_{2,2}=C_4$ in $G$.

Comment: Very clear proof that sorted things in my head along with the answer posted by Uma, thank you!

Comment: @bof I looked up a result of Bondy which proves that the ores condition (δ≥n/2) implies that the graph is either Kn/2,n/2 or pancyclic i.e. has cycles of length 3,4,5...n. Thought you might find it interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, there is a Hamiltonian cycle, say $abc....a$. [since, $\delta(G) \geq n/2$] (You don't need this though, but was the first thought that came to me.)

If $G$ is a complete graph you are done, since $G$ has $k$-cycles for $k=3,4,...,100$. Else $G$ has a triplet $abc$ which is a path.

Now consider this path $abc$, since $deg(a)$ and $deg(c)$ is greater than 50, we need atleast 49 vertices (except $b$) each to be neighbours of $a$ and for $c$, so a total of $98$ vertices. But we have already used up $3$ vertices, hence are left with 97 more vertices. So there exists a vertex $d \neq b$ which is common in $nbd(a)$ and $nbd(c)$.

So $abcda$ is a four cycle. Infact for every induced path $abc$ we have a 4-cycle.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It is not exactly clear to me why we are left with 97 vertices and not 98. Cant a connect directly to c?

Comment: Ok, you are correct. In that case make sure $abc $ is not a triangle. I am editing the answer.

Comment: Thanks once again.. Everything fell into place with both answers combined.

Comment: @BorisAblamunits I looked up a result of Bondy which proves that the ores condition ($\delta \geq n/2$) implies that the graph is either $K_{n/2,n/2}$ or pancyclic i.e. has cycles of length $3,4,5...n$. Thought you might find it interesting.